# Azure setProperties not working with Grunt

Tags: javascript, azure, gruntjs

Using the MS Azure Node sdk, I am trying to change the caching properties on one file. This works, running from the command line with node:

```
var azure = require('azure');
var containerName = '2013-07-10-r49';
var blobName = 'index.html';
var blobService = azure.createBlobService();

blobService.setBlobProperties(containerName,blobName,{cacheControlHeader: 'xxxxx'},function(err,setResponse)
{
    console.log('test');
});
```

That's a standalone node task. But in Grunt, this does not work:

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('setAzureProperty','Mainly used to update cache value for index.html', function()
{
    var azure = require('azure');
    var containerName = '2013-07-10-r49';
    var blobName = 'index.html';
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService();

    blobService.setBlobProperties(containerName,blobName,{cacheControlHeader: 'xxxxxx'},function(err,setResponse)
    {
        var inspect = require('eyes').inspector();
        inspect(setResponse);
    });
});
```

Any suggestions. It just silently does nothing.

Comment: How are you running the grunt task?

Comment: It's part of a larger process which is working. From the command line grunt build:dev. That then calls this task.

Comment: Have also tried running it with grunt setAzureProperty, in otherwords standalone. Same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to set this up as an async task. Not sure why, as I just wanted the value set. However, by telling grunt it's an async task at the start of the task definition:

```
var done = this.async();
```

And then when complete, telling grunt it's done:

```
done(true);
```

It works.